# Three js - accessing objects thats not in the scene

Tags: javascript, object, three.js

Im sorry if this has been asked before, but so far i have not found anything. But my problem is that I want to create two functions where I create a path in one of them and some object in another, lets say a sphere.

```
function makeCurve() {
    var Path = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 70, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 70, 20),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 20)
    );
    Path.id = 'IwantThisPath';
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices = Path.getPoints(50);
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });
    var PathObject = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    PathObject.name = pathname;
    scene.add(PathObject)
}

function sphere() {
    var object = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
    object.overdraw = true;
    sphere.name = spherename;
    scene.add(sphere)
}
```

A textarea would then be linked to those functions and a user would then be able to easily create a sphere and a path by

```
path1 = new makeCurve();
sphere1 = new sphere();
```

I then want to create the third function, where i can make the sphere travel along the path.

```
function along(path, object) {
    name1 = path.name;
    name2 = object.name;
    var MyPath = document.getElementById('IwantThisPath') //givesNull
    myObjPath = scene.getObjectByName(name1); //I don't want this one
    myObjObject = scene.getObjectByName(name2);
    counter = 0;
    var tangent = new THREE.Vector3();
    var axis = new THREE.Vector3();
    var up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    setInterval(moveObject, 50);

    function moveObject() {
        if (counter <= 1) {
            myObjObject.position.copy(myObjPath.getPointAt(counter));

            tangent = myObjPath.getTangentAt(counter).normalize();

            axis.crossVectors(up, tangent).normalize();

            var radians = Math.acos(up.dot(tangent));

            myObjObject.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, radians);
        } else {
            counter = 0
        }
    }
}
```

In the last functions, things get tricky. Because I can't use the PathObject that was added to the scene to make the sphere move, I need the Path made in the beginning. But I cant fetch it, no matter what I try. It's not added to the scene and putting an id or name on it just renders null. 
I hope someone has a better solution for me to solve this problem and that this is clear enough.

For the curious: Im writing a program so I can create three.js animation easier, I want to create teaching material in physics using this.